# Where exactly the store id is set when you create a new customer from adminpanel in M1?

Tags: magento-1, customer

I have a situation when I create a new customer from adminpanel. The store ID is saved as 0 in db. I have a website with 2 stores. If i create a customer from the frontend its working, I got valid store id values in the `customer_entity` table.

I did a `var_dump($customer->getData()); exit();` in the core  in `CustomerController` class in `saveAction` method before `$customer->save();` and there is no any `store_id` array key in the results. Thats why I got `0` values in the db.  What should I do to get a real store id value in the db when I create a new customer from adminpanel ?

Comment: this might help a bit: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/19506/146